# Does ASP.NET MVC 2 get installed with .Net Framework version 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am attempting to deploy an asp.net MVC 2 Application on IIS 6 (windows server 2003), I can access the website looking at a basic html page but it seems that MVC is not working. I am assuming that MVC 2 is installed with version 4 of the .net framework?

The MVC IIS6 walkthrough here http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx looks like its for MVC 1?

Get a 404:page not found error on an expected page and a 403:The website declined to show this webpage when accessing the root (which should route)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the mapping sorted this out: see: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/5c5ae5e0-f4f9-44b0-a743-f4c3a5ff68ec.mspx?mfr=true